# ASP.NET MVC not show ckeditor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

There are one layout page and one page using the layout page. In the `Create` page there is one textarea `id= editor1`. In the  All the js and css were load successful. But the ckeditor not show, just a blank textarea

The output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>SB Admin 2 - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="/css/jquery-ui/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#editor1').ckeditor();
</script>
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </li>
                        <li>

                            <a href="/Home">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Quản lý chung<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/">Quản lý loại</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/BeDanhMuc">Quản lý danh mục</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/BeSach">Quản lý sách</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/BeTacGia">Quản lý tác giả</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/BeNXB">Quản lý nhà xuất bản</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/BeDoiTac">Quản lý đối tác vận chuyển</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/BeTinhThanh">Quản lý tỉnh thành</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/BeDonHang">Quản lý Đơn hàng</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>

                            <a href="/Forms"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Form</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="active" href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">



<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
<h2>Create</h2>

<form action="/BeTacGia/Create" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="kzj5sfQHJry54YaqB11hNT3F_72kkly2EG6JnofMrGtIVcAO4YbNUk7aD1wv7db0OPEEUsVdmvT96Nv_tWPer3RkDY1PMLqJskWGDWkT-WQ1" />    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TacGia</h4>
        <hr />
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Ten">Ten</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Ten" name="Ten" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Ten" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="NgaySinh">NgaySinh</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field NgaySinh must be a date." data-val-required="The NgaySinh field is required." id="ngaySinh" name="NgaySinh" type="datetime" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="NgaySinh" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="NgayMat">NgayMat</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field NgayMat must be a date." id="NgayMat" name="NgayMat" type="datetime" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="NgayMat" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="MaGioiTinh">Giới t&#237;nh</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="MaGioiTinh" name="MaGioiTinh"><option value="False">Nữ        </option>
<option value="True">Nam       </option>
</select>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MaGioiTinh" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <textarea cols="20" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="2">
</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />

            </div>
        </div>
</form>
<div>
    <a href="/BeTacGia">Back to List</a>
</div>

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery -->

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->



    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#editor1").ckeditor();
    </script>
    <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"a0659a041f2c43debc9047700eda9c38"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:51010/3ea56a66c2ef4b65975354424aa8f008/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the edit, it's a little more clear now. This was too long to be a comment.

Here's some things you might want to have a look at

- You have `$('#editor1').ckeditor();` 2 times, remove the first
- You have `<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>` 3 times, remove the 2nd and 3rd
- Replace the 2nd `$('#editor1').ckeditor();` with `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );`

Are you using the CKE jQuery adapter or did you come up with the jQuery-like selector on your own or..? Do you have any errors in your browser dev console?